# how to get width and height from non JPEG image url with loading only 26 bytes?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

i wanted to get width and height information from remote image url without loading full image in memory. while researching about it i found that if image file is not `JPEG` or `TIFF` then we only need to load 26 bytes from the image to get the file information.

so basically i want to load 26 bytes from image url and then want to derive height and width of image from that 26 bytes in python.

i had used below code to get 26 bytes from url.

```
f=urllib2.urlopen(url)
f.read()
```

but i'm unable to figured out how to get height and width data from this 26 bytes.

Comment: Just have a look at how the jpeg header looks like

Comment: i need to do that for non JPEG images. JPEG images doesn't contain height and width and other data in first 26 bytes.